# Mocha and Asynchronous code

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js, synchronous

Would the following code in Mocha be executed synchronously or asynchronously? My aim is to launch these queries concurrently without having to wait for any one query to finish for the other to be executed.

```
describe('test', function(){  

    it('1st', function (done) {
            console.log('1');                    
            done();
           });

    it('2nd', function (done) {
              console.log('2');
              done();
           });

    it('3rd', function (done) {
              console.log('3');
              done();
           });
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: No - these tests will be executed in order.  Using `done` will allow you to call asynchronous methods within your test case but won't make your tests execute in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Anyway I could make these tests execute in parallel?

Comment: It's not supported by mocha [see here](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/issues/98) but perhaps something like [this project](https://github.com/atsuya/parallel-mocha) might work?  (haven't tried this myself)

Comment: From the looks of it, parallel mocha is used to execute multiple files in parallel but in my case I have one .js file which contains the tests described above that need to be executed in parallel. I could be wrong about this though. Shame there aren't any resources which show how parallel mocha could be used.